# AtomicWrites - Permission Error: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python

I have a Windows 10 specific error while using Atomicwrites.

Permission Error: [WinError 5] Access is denied.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more feedback so we can help you. What's the context you get the error in? How can someone else reproduce this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.